# Lower Semicontinuity of Local Variation

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

A function of Locally Bounded Variation has a definition given on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#Locally_BV_functions). (This question doesn't require knowing what it is)

I'm trying to follow the argument they give for showing that local variation is lower semicontinuous. The last equality confuses me:

> Choose a Cauchy sequence of BV-functions $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $u\in L^1_\text{loc}(\Omega)$. Then, since all the functions of the sequence and their limit function are integrable and by the definition of lower limit:
>
> $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}V(u_n,\Omega) \geq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_\Omega u_n(x)\operatorname{div}\, \boldsymbol{\phi}\, \mathrm{d}x \geq \int_\Omega \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n(x)\operatorname{div}\, \boldsymbol{\phi}\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega u(x)\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{\phi}\, \mathrm{d}x $$
> $$\qquad\forall\boldsymbol{\phi}\in C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n),\quad\Vert\boldsymbol{\phi}\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq 1 $$

I'm not clear about the equality on the right. We only know that $\|u_n - u\|_{L^1_{loc}} \rightarrow 0$, not that $\lim u_n(x) = u(x)$ pointwise. Can someone clarify the equality on the right? Thanks!!

Comment: Use the fact that $||\operatorname{div} φ||_\infty < + \infty $ and Holder's inequality to show that $|\int (u_n-u) \operatorname{div}φ | \to 0$

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF could you provide a little more detail? I'm getting that $|\int u_n \, (\nabla \cdot \phi) - \int u \,(\nabla \cdot \phi) | \leq \epsilon$ which implies $\lim \int u_n \, (\nabla \cdot \phi) = \int u \,(\nabla \cdot \phi)$. The limit is still on the outside!

Comment: You are right. Maybe it's a typo. Since $u_n \to u$ in $L^1_{loc}$ we get that $u_n \to u$ weakly, that is, $ \lim \int u_n f = \int u f $ for every $f \in L^\infty$. In particular, $$ \liminf \int u_n \ div φ = \int u \ div φ$$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF  that seems weird though, why would they suppose that $u_n \rightarrow u$ strongly only to use that it weakly converges?

Comment: yeah, it does seem weird... Sometimes Wikipedia is just wrong